# Empty UPDATE way slower than corresponding SELECT

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.1, mysql-5.6

I am using MySQL 5.1.73 with InnoDB

I have a very slow UPDATE query (about 10s), where the number of changed rows is (often) zero (it takes about the same time if there are a few rows changed):

```
UPDATE job_queue SET state=4 WHERE error_counter>=5 AND state=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (9.33 sec)
```

However, the corresponding SELECT is quite fast:

```
SELECT id FROM job_queue WHERE error_counter>=5 AND state=1;
Empty set (0.03 sec)

EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM job_queue WHERE error_counter>=5 AND state=1;
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys                              | key                 | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | job_queue | index | Allinone,state_timeout,state_error_counter | state_error_counter | 5       | NULL | 13515 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
```

As you can see, this is (should be?) an indexed query, on a not-too-big database (about 9000 rows, although it does contain some blobs so the total DB size is about 800MB).

The questions are:

- Why is the update so slow?
- How can I debug it?
- How can I speed it up?

**UPDATE**:
I tried the same database on a different server with MySQL 5.5.35 (Debian wheezy default). The query is still fast, and the update is still slow, and there is still no explain for updates... I may try to upgrade to mysql 5.6 from dotdeb, or try mariadb. :)

**UPDATE 2**: 
I tried different row formats (dynamic and compressed), but it was not (significantly) faster either.

**UPDATE 3**: 
I updated to MySQL 5.6.17 (from dotdeb), and the performance is generally the same, but I finally got an explain for the update:

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE job_queue.job_queue SET state=4 WHERE error_counter>=5 AND state=1;
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | job_queue | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 70222 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

This only confirms what could be suspected all along: the UPDATE is not using any indexes. So the question remains: **WHY**?

I will try to create a minimal example that produces this behaviour; maybe in the course of that, I will find some answers....

Comment: Have a start using mysqls handy `explain` feature. Check the documentation for that.

Comment: Explain for update only available after MySQL 5.6.

Comment: What database engine is this table using? What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE job_queue` say? If you're concerned about speed, MySQL 5.1 is brutally slow compared to 5.5 or 5.6. MySQL 5.1 was released in 2005 and is well past it's "best before" date.

Comment: Ok, sorry, it didn't even occur to me that such an old mysql version is still in use :-)

Comment: I will consider upgrading, this is running currently in a debian squeeze VM, so most probably a full OS upgrade is recommended for mysql upgrade.

Comment: Using InnoDB, as can be read in the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem! The `state` column was defined as `char(1)`. Interestingly, SELECTs containing `state=1` most of the times do use indexes, but UPDATEs never. However, specifying `state="1"` always uses indexes.

So in summary, if `col` is a `char` and `col` is indexed:

```
UPDATE table SET col=2 WHERE col=1
```

will not use an index and thus be *slow*, whereas

```
UPDATE table SET col=2 WHERE col="1"
```

will use an index and thus be *fast*.